# Make "cancel line" thicker

Tags: matrices, brackets, cancel

In the MWE below, I wanted:

1. to make the cancel line with arrow slightly thicker and
2. have the arrow end before the vertical }.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{I}_n = \cancelto{0}{\left.\left(
                  \vphantom{\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{array}}
                  \smash{\underbrace{
                      \begin{array}{ccccc}
                             1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&1&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&0&1&\cdots &0\\
                             \vdots&&&\ddots&\\
                             0&0&0&\cdots &1
                      \end{array}
                      }_{n\text{ columns}}}
              \right)\right\}}
              \,n\text{ rows}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the package has a `[thicklines]` option to use thicker lines, and I think you just want to move the outer `\left.\right\}` outside the `\cancel` (although the spacing may need tweaking a bit more)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{I}_n = \left.\cancelto{0}{\left(
                  \vphantom{\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{array}}
                  \smash{\underbrace{
                      \begin{array}{ccccc}
                             1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&1&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&0&1&\cdots &0\\
                             \vdots&&&\ddots&\\
                             0&0&0&\cdots &1
                      \end{array}
                      }_{n\text{ columns}}}
              \right)}\quad\right\}
              \,n\text{ rows}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```